# Android studio AVD internet access

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I am using Android studio 3.0.1 and that is working really very fine. I have upto date SDK version and I have upto date gradle version.

Everything seems to be perfect now. But I am now facing a problem and I have no idea why it is occurring.

Problem: 
Whenever I try to access webservices my emulator/AVD never access that. Also I am unable to access the internet using emulator browser. Even it is unable to open the Google.com page.

I have searched this problem but non of them is working for me. I have checked the Ip configrations and that is totally fine. I am not using any specific DNS settings and I am not using any special VPN network. My network adapter is just fine. I am using Windows 7

Please help me if anyone of you having solution of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are couple of cases i want to discuss. And that is totally what I dig out after trying for hours.

I have same Issue. and for this I have seen that there was nothing wrong with the AVD i was creating again and again. But I was using Windows 10 and using android studio over it.

The problem was the virtual networks. I got them created for the Blue stacks and GeneyMotion emulator. They sets the IP and the DNS them self for virtual network

SO if you are having virtual network set their IP to defaults. OR disable them at all. Also disable other networks except the one you are using.

and after doing this all. Create the new AVD and check if that starts working.